# Writing singleton component that will reference only one element

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I need to dynamically insert social embeds and in order to run scripts, I want to insert them into head, similar to how jQuery's `.html()` is doing. How would I go about writing component that I can inject into other components but will always reference head of document? I tried this:

```
@Decorator(
    selector: 'head'
)
@Injectable()
class ScriptLoader {
    Element element;

    ScriptLoader(this.element) {
    }

    loadScript(String url) {
        ScriptElement script = new ScriptElement();
        script.src = url;
        script.setAttribute("async", "");
        script.onLoad.listen((Event e) {
            script.remove();
        });
        element.append(script);
    }
}
```

and when page is loaded, `this.element` is a reference to head but when it is injected into other component, it throws with error `No provider found for Element! (resolving ExecuteBindHTML -> ScriptLoader -> ScriptLoader -> Element)`. How would I go about implementing such component? I don't want to use querySelectors (because Angular).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the head element with `querySelector` directly in the constructor.

```
@Injectable()
class ScriptLoader {
  Element element;

  ScriptLoader() {
    element = querySelector("head");
  }
}
```

Then add the `ScriptLoader` class to the bootstrap method directly.